# Schema.org Microdata broadest tag check

Tags: html5, microdata

I have defined the tag that can sit on all the pages of my website and be easily integrated into the admin tool. It is the broadest category with properties that are relevant for all pages.

Can you please tell me if it is written correctly?

I am concerned that the URL code line might be picked up as a circular link and as a result be penalised by the Search Engine:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
    <span itemprop="name">TITLE OF PAGE</span>
    <span itemprop="description">CONTENT OF PAGE</span>
    <link itemprop="url" href="jmb-active.com/?page=URL-OF-THIS-PAGE">TITLE OF PAGE</a>
    <img itemprop="image" src="NAME OF IMAGE.jpg" alt="ALT NAME OF IMAGE"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What can/does this `Thing` represent on your site? Does it always appear on a page with the same URL like the one specified in `url`, or can several of these `Thing` items appear on one page?

Comment: This Thing code will be automatically on all pages. Yes it will appear on a page with a URL similar to the one in the code jmb-active.com/?page=xxxx There will be only one Thing code per page. Underneath inside the page there will be other codes that are specific to each page for Offers, Products, Services, etc...

Comment: Since I wrote this code I realised 2 new things: 1. Instead of using the category  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing"> I could use <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TravelAgency"> which is more specific to my type of business and still use the same properties 2. It is probably best for the description property to NOT contain the entire content of the page but only a short description. What do you think? Is it a better use of the microdata tagging capabilities? Thanks for your feedback Unor!

Comment: @Unor I have created 2 separate tags summarising all the feedback you have given me. One for the home page and one for the product pages. What do  you think? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78085/schema-org-microdata-code-check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Schema.org

Assuming that the [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing) represents your organization/business on each page of your site, you should try to find a more specific type, e.g., [`TravelAgency`](http://schema.org/TravelAgency) as you point out in the comments.
[Every Schema.org type is also implicitly a `Thing`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/69598/17633), so every type can use the basic properties from `Thing`.

The [`description` property](http://schema.org/description) is not for the full content, but only for a "short description" (of the `TravelAgency` in your case, so it would likely always be the same).

In the same way would the value of the [`image` property](http://schema.org/image) have to show an image of the `TravelAgency`, not just any image.

And the [`url` property](http://schema.org/url) would be for the URL of the item, i.e., the `TravelAgency`, so it would always be the same URL (typically the URL of the home page), no matter on which page.

That said, if you want to have an item that represents each page (and not the business all these pages belong to), you probably want to use [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) (or one of its sub-types) in addition.

#### Microdata

Syntactically, your Microdata is fine.

#### HTML5

Your HTML5 is fine, too, apart from a small error: You have a closing `</a>` tag after the `link` element. You probably want to either use `link` (i.e., the link is invisible) or `a` (i.e., the link is visible).

Comment: Thx Unor! 1. I have found this category that suits our business even better: http://schema.org/MedicalWebPage and we can use aspect=treatment as we offer a broad range of medical treatments abroad. 2. It seems better to take out the url property altogether. It does give the search engine any relevant information 3. Regarding the description property I agree that it should be a short description. But I am surprised. I wanted the description to be tailored to each page to reflect its content. For example one page is cancer treatment, the other one is plastic surgery.

Comment: @Julien: 1. You could use *both* items together on each page: `MedicalWebPage` represents the page and `TravelAgency` represents your business this page belongs to (use an appropriate property to link these two, e.g., [`author`](http://schema.org/author)). 2. It does help if used on `TravelAgency`, because that way consumers can learn that this `TravelAgency` is always the same one (identified by the home page URL, for example). 3. The description (like any other property) always belongs to its parent item. So if used on `MedicalWebPage`, you can have a different description for each page.