# Schema.org combining different categories

Tags: html5, microdata

This is the follow up version of a [previous question](/q/78085) on combining different categories and their properties.

The home page contains the overarching company information.
The product page contains product information and links to the home page.

I do not get any error messages in Google testing tool. But I feel that the code is clunky. I am concerned that a lot of the information is hidden and that search prefer to index information that is also visible to the user.

**Home page**

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/">Organization</a>
<meta itemprop="name" content="Organizaton name" />
<img itemprop="image" src="company-logo.jpg" alt="Image-alt-name"/>
<p itemprop="description">short description on home page</p>
</body>
```

**Product page**

```
<body itemprop="branchOf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" id="schema-organization">

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TravelAgency" itemref="schema-organization">
<link itemprop="url" href="http://www.sub-company-url/">                
<meta itemprop="name" content="Sub-company name" />


<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

<span itemprop="name">NAME OF PRODUCT</span>
The cost of
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<span itemprop="itemOffered">NAME OF PRODUCT</span>
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR">€</span><span itemprop="price" content="600.00">600</span>
</div></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Home page

The Microdata is fine.

I don’t know if it’s possible with the design of your page, but typically you would link the name/logo (then you could omit the `meta` and you wouldn’t need `alt` content), so it could look like:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/">
    <img itemprop="image" src="company-logo.jpg" alt="" /> <!-- empty alt because the 'name' already describes the link target -->
    <span itemprop="name">Organizaton</span>
  </a>
  <p itemprop="description">short description on home page</p>
</body>
```

#### Product page

- You are using the `name` property (from `TravelAgency`) on a `meta` element, but do you really have no visible name of the travel agency on your page (e.g., in the header)? If you have one, you could use that element instead of `meta`.
- The [`itemOffered` property](http://schema.org/itemOffered) expects a `Product` item as value, but you are using text.

  As you are already using `Product → offers → Offer`, there is no need for the reverse relation `Offer → itemOffered → Product`.

  You probably want to use the `name` property instead, however, if the `Product` has the same name as the `Offer`, omit this property altogether.
- If the only data about the `Product` is the name, consider omitting this item. You could use `Offer` directly (unless you have several offers for the same `Product`).
- There is a superfluous `</span>`.
- Your `span` element has a [`content` attribute, which is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27089168/1591669). Use a `meta` or `data` element (or in your specific case, just the content of the `span`.)

Comment: Thank you for your very useful feedback! I have cleaned up the code and tested it with Google. There are no error messages. I am not much of a coder as you know but if I can be of help in the future please let me know. All the best. Julien :-)